# Angular in docker compose does not reload changes

Tags: angularjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I am trying to make an aplication using django-rest and angular. My current docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=pirate
      - POSTGRES_USER=django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secreat
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  backend:
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
    build: ./backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    healthcheck:
        test: [“CMD”, “curl”, “--fail”, 'http://localhost:8000']
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 3
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    healthcheck:
        test: [“CMD”, “curl”, “--fail”, 'http://localhost:4200']
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 3
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    healthcheck:
        test: [“CMD”, “curl”, “--fail”, 'http://localhost']
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 3
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - frontend
volumes:
  db-data:
```

And this is my angular Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.6
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

# Here starts angular cli workaround
USER node
RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
# Here ends 

COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And now this is the problem: Whenever I change sth in my angular code the docker image with angular does not reload changes. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you restarting the docker container/all docker containers with your new code?

Comment: When I change angular code I suppose it will reload changes automatically without docker compose stop and then start again.

Comment: The thing is, or at least as far as I know. When you run the container, it will use the source code is has at that moment. If you have new source code, you have to rebuild your container.

Answer (score 2):

THe problem is related to how the filesystem works in Docker. To fix this I suggest you to either perform hot reloads (you have add `EXPOSE 49153` in Dockerfile and ports `- '49153:49153'` in docker-compose.yml)

There are other solution like inotify or nodemon but they require that you use the --poll option when you start your application. The problem is that they keep polling the fs for changes and if the application is big your machine will be a lot slower than you'd like.

---

I think I found the issue. You copy the `./app` in `/usr/src/app` but you're setting `.:/app` as a volume. So this means that if you get in your docker instance you'll find your application in 2 places: `/app` and `/usr/src/app`.

To fix this you should have this mapping: `.:/usr/src/app`

Btw, you're going to use the `node_modules` from your host and this might create some issues. To avoid this you can add an empty volume mapping: `/usr/src/app/node_modules`

---

If you get inside your running container, you'll find that the folder `app` exists twice. You can try it, by executing:

```
docker exec -it $instanceName /bin/sh
ls /app
ls /usr/src/app
```

The problem is that only the content of `/app` changes during your coding, while your application is currently executing the content of `/usr/src/app` which remains always the same.

Your `frontend` in the docker-compose should look like this:

```
frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Comment: Hi I added both things but still changes dont reload.

Comment: well the hot reload means that you've got to hit that page with your browser to have it working. Concerning the inotify, you should start the angular application using `ng serve --poll`

Comment: Ok I am not sure we understand each other. My situation is that I have docker compose up and I am developing angular. When I write some code and save, angular wont reload this changes not even when i reload page. I add ng serve --poll to package.json but stil nothing. I can see changes only when I stop docker compose and start again.

Comment: Can you add the content of you packages.json (just the script part)

Comment: "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --poll -H 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json"
  }

Comment: I think I found the issue. You copy the `./app` in `/usr/src/app` but you're setting `.:/app` as a volume. So this means that if you get in your docker instance you'll find your application in 2 places: `/app` and  `/usr/src/app`. To fix this you should have this mapping: `.:/usr/src/app`

Comment: so you say that i should replace every /usr/src/app with .:/usr/src/app in frontend dockerfile and also in docker-compose i should place it as volume ?

Comment: uhm no, I say that you should change your volume mapping to be `.:/usr/src/app` instead of `.:/app`

Comment: ok i did but than I should change also DockerFile or ? In docker-compose log I am getting error `npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json`. Sorry am really new to docker :(

Comment: I hope you read my last edits in the answer. Anyway this is strange since the packages.json already exists in that folder.

Comment: I changed exactly everything like u said ... docker-compose build will go but when i run docker-compose up i got this error in log `npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json` still the same. I dont know whats wrong because I copy it there.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue in Docker Desktop for Windows. I know it has been a while but, anybody came here looking for a answer like me, you should do these steps.

Modify `start` command to `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 500"` on `scripts` section in `package.json`. (Here the number `500` means that client will check every 500 milliseconds whether a change has been made, you can reduce this number. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930195/what-is-the-function-of-poll-flag-in-cli))

Make sure port `49153` is exposed in `Dockerfile` (use correct node version)

```
FROM node:10.16.3-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200 49153
CMD npm run start
```

Map ports and volumes in `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "49153:49153"
    volumes:
      - "/app/node_modules"
      - ".:/app"
```

After that running `docker-compose up` will build an image and spin up a new container which will automatically reload with new changes.

Comment: `--poll 500` did it for me. I don't see how `EXPOSE` would be needed.