# Angular ng build --watch in Remote containers and Remote WSL not detecting file changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular-cli

The command `ng build --watch` does not appear to be working (detecting file changes) when developing an Angular project remotely (using Remote WSL and/or Remote containers) in Visual Studio Code.

Is this a known problem? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 7):

Since posting I have found a solution/workaround using the `--poll` switch.

From comment made by https://github.com/JSMike at  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1814#issuecomment-241854816

> In cases where Angular CLI is running in a shared directory on linux VM on a windows host the webpack dev server isn't detecting file changes from the host environment. (ex: Whenever a docker dev environment is running on a windows host.) This is solved by adding poll option to the webpack dev server configuration. **By default when no poll interval is set watchpack will use native file system change detection.** This change allows for setting the poll interval which will turn on polling.

Modify your `package.json` by adding the `--poll 500` option.

Depending on your workflow/needs, add the `--poll ms` switch where ms is the polling interval.

```
"start": "ng serve --poll 500",
```

```
"watch": "ng build --watch --poll 500 --configuration development",
```

Further details can be found at the links below.

[docker-container-doesnt-reload-angular-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176922/docker-container-doesnt-reload-angular-app)

[what-is-the-function-of-poll-flag-in-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930195/what-is-the-function-of-poll-flag-in-cli)